# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'key'

Tags: python, linked-list

I keep getting this error while working with a linked list and I just wanted to see how I could fix it

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'key'
```

Here is the code :

```
  def create_inventory(self, countryinfo):

    with open('datafiles/CountryInfo.csv', "r") as csvfile:
      csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
      for line in csvreader:

        country = Country()

        country.country_name = line[0]
        country.country_code = line[1]
        country.industry_male = float(line[2])
        country.industry_female = float(line[3])
        country.agriculture_male = float(line[4])
        country.agriculture_female = float(line[5])
        country.unemployment_male = float(line[6])
        country.unemployment_female = float(line[7])
        country.population_male = float(line[8])
        country.population_female = float(line[9])

        self.__country_dict[country.country_name] = country
```

This line of code is giving me the problem:

```
    self.__country_dict[country.country_name] = country
```

self.__country_dict is assigned here:
self.__country_dict = LLDict()

This is the LLDict class:

```
class LLDict(DictAbstract):

  def __init__(self):
    
    self.head = None
    self.tail = None
    self.count = 0 
  
  def __len__(self):
    return self.count

  def __contains__(self, key):
    current = self.head
    while current:
      if current.key == key:
        return True
      current == current.next
    return False
    
  def __getitem__(self, key):
    current = self.head
    while current:
      if current.key == key:
        return current.value
      current = current.next
    raise KeyError(key)
    

  def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    current = self.head
    while current.key == key:
      current.value = value
      return
      current = current.next
      node = Node(key, value)
      if self.head is None:
        self.head = node
      else:
        self.tail.next = node
        self.tail = node
        self.count += 1
        

  def pop(self, key):
    current = self.head
    prev = None
    while current:
      if current.key == key:
        if prev:
          prev.next = current.next
        else:
          self.head = current.next
        if current.next is None:
          self.tail = prev
          self.count -= 1
        return current.value
      prev = current
      current = current.next
    raise KeyError(key)          


  def print_dict(self):
    current = self.head
    while current:
      print(current.key, current.value)
      current = current.next
```

I am not sure if I need to fix the LLDict class. Any advice would be a big help and thank you

Comment: How does `self.__country_dict` get assigned?

Comment: self.__country_dict = LLDict() I am importing "LLDict()" from another .py file where a method replaces an existing node with a key and adds it to the end of the linked list

Comment: And where/when does this happen?  You didn't include the code for it.

Comment: Apologies, I included the code for that class.

Comment: Your `__setitem__` looks buggy - what's up with the `return` in the middle of the loop?

Comment: My professor gave us the code for the LLDict class, so I really do not know what is going on with __setitem__

Comment: Have you used a debugger and stepped through the code and inspected variables? What were your findings?